# OpenCV GPU Dilate not working

Tags: opencv, gpu

I'm trying to execute a Dilate and Erode functions using OpenCV GPU, but for some reason it is returning a black image. I just can't figure out what's the issue;

The code that I'm using:

```
int erosionDilation_size = 5;
Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(2*erosionDilation_size + 1,    2*erosionDilation_size+1));
cv::gpu::dilate(_gpuProcessOutput[__n],  _gpuProcessOutput[__n],element);
_gpuProcessOutput[__n].download(_frame[__n]);
imshow("Test",_frame[0]);
cvWaitKey(1000/120);
```

Does anyone know what's happening? Thanks!

*Update*
This is the image that I'm trying to dilate!
[image: Image1]

Comment: But can you post an image which on this code returns black image?

Comment: I've edited the main thread with the image! Thanks!

Comment: I think element should be uploaded to device.

Comment: That was uploaded already, I just haven't added the line on the code above. I'm uploading it using the following code: cv::Mat _tempMat; _capture>>_tempMat; _gpuFrame[__n].upload(_tempMat);

Comment: Could you solve the problem?. If you did.. you can tell us how please?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
    #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/cudafilters.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace cv::cuda;

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int main ( int argc, char** argv )
    {
        cv::cuda::setDevice(0);
        // -------------------------------
        // 
        // -------------------------------
    Mat img=imread("test.png",0);
    int erosionDilation_size = 5;
    Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(2*erosionDilation_size + 1,    2*erosionDilation_size+1));

    cuda::GpuMat d_element(element);
    cuda::GpuMat d_img(img);

    Ptr<cuda::Filter> dilateFilter = cuda::createMorphologyFilter(MORPH_DILATE, d_img.type(), element);
    dilateFilter->apply(d_img, d_img);


    d_img.download(img);

    d_img.release();
    d_element.release();

    imshow("test",img);
    waitKey();
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, still looking good in 2021. Thanks too for including the header file references - it's amazing how often they get left out!!

Comment: What is `cuda::GpuMat d_element(element);` used for ?

Comment: It just makes structuring element (which is just a rectangular matrix filled with ones), in other cases it may contain some binaary pattern like an ellipse or cross), In most cases I usually use cv::Mat::ones(h,w,CV_8UC1). You also can fill if manually with pattern you like . Check here for more details: https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm